Apache Camel - How to download multiple files and what is best approach for this
Below are the details for the issue I am having , and need you guidance
Requirement -

Initialize set of parameters/get the sftp path/source files path.
Download/Read the files.
next steps.

Approach -
from("timer:timer-start?repeatCount=1")
//read file here or download file here
.to("direct:testing-direct")

Example -

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication extends RouteBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
       from("timer:timer-start?repeatCount=1")
    
             .log("Running timer...")
    
             .pollEnrich("file:D:\\learning\\source?noop=true", 5000)
    
             .log("File content: ${body}")
    
             .to("direct:testing-direct");
    
       from("direct:testing-direct")
             .to("file:D:\\learning\\destination");
    }

}


Issue -
This process wait after downloading/reading first file.
I've tried loop over pollEnrich() , which is able to download the files, but still waits after this.
Question -
what will the right/better approach here.
Why camel does not supports this (or am I missing something here).
Am I expecting camel to do something it is not even suppose to do.
Thanks

I need a bit of clarification on your question. pollEnrich reads a local file in your example. In my experience, it does so without any delay. Where exactly do you experience waiting time?

If you try the example shared above, you can replicate this,  upon reading/copying first file, program waits, and does not read/copy remaining files. I am not clear on what is actually happening at that stage.

Your code only copies one file. The application keeps on running unless you configure Camel to shut down automatically. Is your question how to read all files in a directory?

yes, your understanding is correct. I need to read all files in the directory, and looking for right approach for it. This seems a very trivial task, but camel implementation is not so.  My concern is, am I expecting camel to do something it is not even suppose to do.

AFAIK, there is no built-in way to do it, but you can write a custom processor to iterate over all files in a directory.

understood, thanks for looking into this, and for your advice.

Give this a read. Ig might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520916/apache-camel-how-to-download-multiple-files-from-sftp-with-premove-move-and-mo
